# How to get new TOC format?

Tags: table-of-contents

This is what I want :

```
                    CONTAINT 

CONTAINT .............................................................. i

TABLE ...................................................................... ii

FIGURE .................................................................... iii

APPENDIX ................................................................ iv

CHAPTER I   PENDAHULUAN .................................... 1 

              1.1 Latar Belakang ................. 2
              1.2 Kontribusi ..................... 3
CHAPTER II  KAJIAN TEORI ...................................... 4

              2.1 Landasan Teori ................. 4
              2.2 Studi Pendahuluan .............. 5
```

I use the `report` class.
Could anyone help me please? I'm very beginner in LaTeX and I have to write a large document with LaTeX for my bachelor graduation.

my code doesn't work well :

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large\MakeUppercase} 
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{% 
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne 
        \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}% 
        \vskip 1.0em 
        \@plus\p@ 
        \setlength\@tempdima{4.5em}% 
        \begingroup 
            \parindent \z@ 
            \rightskip \@pnumwidth 
            \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth 
            \leavevmode \normalfont % mengganti bfseries menjadi normal font
            \advance\leftskip\@tempdima 
            \hskip -\leftskip 
            #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par 
            \penalty\@highpenalty 
        \endgroup
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The `tocloft` package can do this quite easily. If you search for 'tocloft' on the site you can find many examples of it in use.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you mean by your code "doesn't work well". It doesn't compile? What error do you get? It compiles but doesn't look right? Where are the problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=40mm,top=40mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}

\newcommand{\newchapter}[1]%
{   \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}%
    \chapter{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}%
}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{4.5}   % same spacing as for sections

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER }
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.8cm}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDIX}
\chapter*{APPENDIX}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\newchapter{FIRST CHAPTER}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \section{first section}
    \section{second section}

\newchapter{SECOND CHAPTER} 
    \section{third section}
    \section{fourth section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It appears you want bigger right margins for `\sections{}`, but the [`tocloft` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) states that it "should remain constant in any given document", so I'm not sure if you should change it. Probably there is another way?

The `\newchapter{}` just changes from arabic to roman for the chapter label itself, so the section labels are unaffected.

Comment: wow, that's great, thanks for this, I'll try than for both at TexMaker and Lyx

Comment: Hii Tom, I've tried yours and as expected it running well in my Texmaker. But I have a problem when I use it in Lyx. I put the code in the preamble. No warning error. but I got my toc with no "chapter". it seem the code "\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER }" doesn't work in my Lyx. I use the same class,report. could you help me Tom?

Comment: I don't use Lyx, but potentially I had something to do with missing `%`? I added them at the end of each line, please try again?

Comment: I'm sorry Tom, It seems I really need yor help, can I sent my code to your e-mail ? I create a class file and I combine with your code, it works well when I use it without tocloft package, but when I use that package, all of the format are unformatted. could you help me please?

Comment: I'm not a pro, so I probably won't find the answer alone. I think it is best you post your code here (or in a new question), as there are many very skilled people on this platform. While I *might* find an answer after a very long time, people here usually can find a better solution than mine within a few days.